# Build Fails with NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.StreamingExtensions.NetCore

Tags: azure-devops, botframework

I am trying to set up a DevOps pipeline with Azure DevOps and BotFramework. My build is failing due to the package `Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.StreamingExtensions.NetCore` with the error `NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.StreamingExtensions.NetCore. No packages exist with this id in source(s): NuGetOrg`

I tried to uninstall this package, but then I started getting the same error locally. When I tried to reinstall I couldn't find the package on NuGet which is probably why this error is occurring, so I had to revert to a previous commit to get a working version of my bot.

It would be expected for the package to be able to be installed when the project is being built on Azure DevOps. Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Build Fails with NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.StreamingExtensions.NetCore

That because **the package `Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.StreamingExtensions.NetCore` was only published to the `myget.org` Not `nuget.org`**. That is also the reason why the error message show that *this id in source(s): NuGetOrg*.

You can find that package on the `myget.org`:

```
https://botbuilder.myget.org/gallery/experimental
```

Then get the URL to connect the feed is:

```
https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/experimental/api/v3/index.json
```

**To resolve this issue on Azure DevOps**, you can add a `nuget.config` under the solution folder with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyGetFeed" value="https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/experimental/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />   
  </packageSources>     
</configuration>
```

Then submit and push this file to the Azure Devops repos. Use this file when you restore nuget packages:

[image]

As test, it works fine on my side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note - for anyone pretty new to azure devops, setting the path to NuGet.config is just a task and should go under the `steps` key in the `azure-pipelines.yml`
It looks something like this:
`steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.Config'`